# How to get a method's annotation value from a ProceedingJoinPoint?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-3, java-ee-7

I have below annotation.

### MyAnnotation.java

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

### SomeAspect.java

```
public class SomeAspect{

 @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")
    public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {

  //Some logic

}

}
```

### SomeOther.java

```
public class SomeOther{

@MyAnnotation("ABC") 
public String someMethod(String name){


}


}
```

In above class am passing "**ABC**" with in **@MyAnnotation**.
Now how can i access "**ABC**" value in **procede** method of **SomeAspect.java** class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You can get the [Signature](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/Signature.html) from a [ProceedingJoinPoint](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html) and in case of a method invocation just cast it to a [MethodSignature](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/reflect/MethodSignature.html).

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")
public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) call.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();

    MyAnnotation myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
}
```

But you should first add an annotation attribute. Your example code doesn't have one, e.g.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

    String value();
}
```

Then you can access it

```
MyAnnotation myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
String value = myAnnotation.value();
```

**EDIT**

> How to get value if I have @MyAnnotation("ABC") at class level ?

A `Class` is also an [`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html), so you can get it the same way as from a `Method`. E.g. An annotation of the method's declaring class can be obtained using

```
 Method method = ...;
 Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
 MyAnnotation myAnnotation = declaringClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)
```

Since you are using spring you might also want to use spring's [`AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(..)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html). It searches for an annotation as spring does. E.g. also looking at superclass and interface methods, etc.

```
 MyAnnotation foundAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, MyAnnotation.class);
```

**EDIT**

You might also be interessted in the capabilities of spring's [`MergedAnnotations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/MergedAnnotations.html) which was introduced in 5.2.

Comment: @user755806 Your annotation example doesn't define an attribute yet. I updated my answer, but I recommend you to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Comment: Is there a way to change value of that annotation there?

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. I was struggling with this the whole day. Thanks!

Comment: Seems that `signature.getMethod()` does not longer exist.

Answer (score 49):

Actually I think we can get the `value` in another way round instead of just from **ProceedingJoinPoint**, which will definitely require us to make use of `reflection`.

Have a try as follows using annotation directly: add `com.mycompany.MyAnnotation yourAnnotation` in your `advice params` and `@annotation(yourAnnotation)` in `@Around`.

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(yourAnnotation)")
public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, com.mycompany.MyAnnotation yourAnnotation) {
    ...
    yourAnnotation.value(); // get your annotation value directly;
    ...
}
```

`com.mycompany.MyAnnotation` in advice params just work as that in

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")
```

`yourAnnotation` can be valid variable name since `MyAnnotation` in params already points out which annotation it should be. Here `yourAnnotation` is used to retrieve the annotation instance only.

If you want to pass more params you can try `args()`.

For more details, do please check its official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). For Annotation value, you can just search `@Auditable`.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, as it is cleaner and the documented way: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: I agree (should be accepted answer), this is definitely the way to go. Accepted answer, although correct, is very clunky.

Comment: Will this work with plain AspectJ or only with Spring-AOP?

Comment: @JakubBochenski As far as I know, Spring AOP is built upon AspectJ, and so basically if Spring AOP can do the trick, AspectJ should support it in some way. But I have not tried it myself ;p

Comment: "Should" is a big word here... fortunately I've checked this in practice and it does work

Comment: As mentioned above by other users, the accepted answer works but I think this should be the accepted answer because is straightforward and officially documented, exactly in this section: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-names.

Answer (score 3):

This works as well - You can fetch annotation information using reflection on the class.

```
Annotation anno = MyClass.class.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```

Or

```
Annotation anno = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("somethod").getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```

This works only if your annotation is available at runtime, which you have declared correctly.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

Comment: which Annotation class do you use, there are more than one

Comment: The trick is to declare a @PointCut with the annotation like:

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation))")
    public void myAnnotation() {}

and then reference it in your advice like so:

    @Before("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public void beforeSqsListener(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation myAnnotation) {
        // use myAnnotation like a normal variable...
    }

Comment: Sorry about the "code blocks" in previous comment. I'm simply not able to markup code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

**René's** example is taking me a long way.  Also the explanation how I get ClassLevel Annotations.

But then I can only read ClassLevel Annotations Values if I have previously used a method annotation with "*@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(com.mycompany.MyAnnotation)")"*"

How can I get around this? How can I trigger an Aspect if a ClassLevel Annotation is set without going through a Method Execution?

I want to write a ClassLevel Annotation like

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@EnableSwagger2
@Import(SwaggerConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableSwaggerApi {
    String controllerPackage() default "foo.bar.ctrl";
}
```

It's importing the Configuration about "SwaggerConfiguration" where I want to receive the value of "controllerPackage"

```
@Aspect
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Value("${tom.swagger.controller.package:foo.bar.notset}")
    private String  controllerPackage;

    @Value("${tom.swagger.api.version:1.0.0}")
    private String  apiVersion;

    @Value("${spring.application.name:MyApplication}")
    private String  applicationName;

    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(EnableSwaggerApi)")
    public void procede(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) call.getSignature();
        Method method = signature.getMethod();

        Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
        EnableSwaggerApi myAnnotation = declaringClass.getAnnotation(EnableSwaggerApi.class);
        System.err.println("1 -> " + myAnnotation.controllerPackage());  // -> tko.backend.spring.ctrl

        myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(EnableSwaggerApi.class);
        System.err.println("2 -> " + myAnnotation.controllerPackage()); // -> tko.backend.spring.SOMEOTHERSTUFF


        // THIS WORKS, BUT JUST IF I USE THE @EnableSwaggerApi ON SOME METHOD!
        // NOT ON CLASS

    }

    @Bean
    public Docket swaggerApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("controllerPackage"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().version(apiVersion).title(applicationName).description("Documentation " + applicationName + " API v" + apiVersion)
                        .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}





@EnableSwaggerApi(controllerPackage="tko.backend.spring.ctrl")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class, Initializer.class);
    }


    @Bean
    @EnableSwaggerApi(controllerPackage="tko.backend.spring.SOMEOTHERSTUFF")
    public String initSwagger() {
        return "some dummy";
    }

}
```

How can I can rid of the annotation on *initSwagger()*?  Since the *Application.class* is not known to *SwaggerConfiguration* (Swagger Stuff it's in a separate lib) I can't use simple reflection like

```
Application.class.getAnnotation(EnableSwaggerApi.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Find working code for Method Annotation and class level annotation using AspectJ/AOP

```
   @Around("execution(* com.first.test.controller..*(..)))")
    public Object profileAllMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable
    {
        MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature();

        java.lang.reflect.Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();

  Annotation []methodAnnotations =  method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        System.out.println("==============="+methodAnnotations[0].toString());

        Annotation []classAnnotations = proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotations();

        System.out.println("===Class Annotation : "+classAnnotations[1].toString());
       Object result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply bind the method's as described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing).

MyAnnotation.java

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

SomeAspect.java

```
public class SomeAspect{

 @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object procede(ProceedingJoinPoint call, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {

  //Some logic

  }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work, a method annotated with @Around must have only one parameter of type `ProceedingJoinPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

##### [Using AspectJ with Spring Applications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html) <sup>aspectjweaver 1.8.5</sup>

To calculate the execution time of methods and access annotation values using AspectJ, AspectJ is a powerful framework for cross-cutting concerns in Java applications, including aspects like performance monitoring and method-level annotations. The following example is used to create an Aspect for Measuring Execution Time for the `@RequestMapping` annotation and get the `endpoint value` along with its execution time.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class EndpointTimeAspect {

    //@Around("execution(* com.myapp.resource.*.*(..) )")
    @Around("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
        
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
        
        org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature signature = (org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        java.lang.reflect.Method method = signature.getMethod();
        Class<?> declaringClass = method.getDeclaringClass();
        
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping ann = 
                AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping.class);
        
        String[] value = ann.value();
        String path = "";
        for (String string : value) {
            path += string;
        }
        
        System.out.println("["+ signature +" ], Time taken for endpoint [ " +path +" ] : " + timeTaken + " ms");
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

> [AspectJ to calculate execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398315/5081877)