# AspectJ to calculate execution time

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

In this scenario, `method1` calls `method2`.

There is a pointcut and advice defined on each of the method execution to calculate time taken by the method.
So,

```
   advice of `method1` prints 10 seconds; 

   advice of `method2` prints 6 seconds;
```

I want to print the time taken by `method1` excluding the time taken by `method2`. That is I want `10-6 = 4 seconds` as result

How can I acheive this using aspect ?

Expected : 4 seconds

Code snippet :

```java
public int method1( String input ){
   User user = null;
   // something .. 
   method2(input, input2);
   return 100;
}
```

Here is the check method in aspect component:

```java
@PointCut("....something correct")
public void endpoint (ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

@Around("endpoint")
public void timeTaken(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
     
     //code to calcualte start time
     pjp.proceed();
     printf("the total time " : currentTime - startTime);
}
```

Comment: There are profiling tools giving exactly the results you're aiming for, without necessity to add any special statements to your code.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff  Your are right but I would need this only in my problem statement. I have mentioned the problem statement in the simplest way possible.( there are complexities around it ) These  info are needed to for log.io logging.

Comment: Got it. You need it within your application for logging purposes.

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible, but complex to emulate a profiler by means of AOP. The reason is that you would need to calculate a method call tree and record it along with the execution times in a separate data structure. When logging, you would have to subtract execution times of everything in a subtree from the measured time. This would cost CPU cycles, memory and lots of maintenance work. One more issue is asynchronous code, i.e. multi-threading.

My recommendation is to take a step back and think about why you even think you need this. The only reason is that your `method1` mixes (time-consuming) logic with calling other methods also containing (time-consuming) logic.

Have you ever heard about the [**Integration Operation Segregation Principle (IOSP)**](https://clean-code-developer.com/grades/grade-1-red/#:%7E:text=Integration%20Operation%20Segregation%20Principle%20(IOSP),-Why%3F&text=IOSP%20calls%20for%20a%20clear,control%20structures%20or%20API%20invocations.&text=Or%20a%20method%20does%20not,methods%20within%20its%20code%20basis)? It basically states that there are two types of methods:

- **operations** containing logic
- **integrations** only calling operations

If you apply this principle to your own code, you indirectly get the numbers you are interested in as a side effect.

So if you run this aspect

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class TimerAspect {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && within(de.scrum_master..*) && !within(TimerAspect)")
  public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    try {
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    finally {
      System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000 + " ms");
    }
  }
}
```

against this application

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Application().method1("foo");
  }

  public int method1(String input) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(300);
    method2(input, 11);
    Thread.sleep(100);
    return 100;
  }

  public void method2(String input, int i) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(600);
  }
}
```

you get the problematic output you don't like:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.method2(String, int)) -> 604 ms
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.method1(String)) -> 1009 ms
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])) -> 1010 ms
```

But if you refactor your application code according to the IOSP like this

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    new Application().integration("foo");
  }

  public int integration(String input) throws InterruptedException {
    operation1();
    operation2(input, 11);
    operation3();
    return 100;
  }

  private void operation1() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(300);
  }

  public void operation2(String input, int i) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(600);
  }

  private void operation3() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
}
```

the application still does the same, but all logical and possible expensive operations are factored out into their own methods. `operation2` is the same as `method2` before, `operation1` is the logic happening before and `operation3` is the logic happening after and `operation2`. Now not only is your `integration` (formerly `method1`) cleaner and easier to read but also do you get separate timing logs for each operation:

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.operation1()) -> 302 ms
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.operation2(String, int)) -> 599 ms
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.operation3()) -> 100 ms
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.integration(String)) -> 1005 ms
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.Application.main(String[])) -> 1005 ms
```

Of course the `Thread.sleep` operations are just symbolical representations for whatever application logic you might have: `if` or `switch - case` statements, loops, external resource (file, database) handling, complex calculations or whatever.

Bottom line: **Go refactor!** Don't mix operations and integrations if you want to time, test, refactor, use them separately. Alternatively, use a profiler.

Comment: Absolutely correct about the responsibility segregation part. Totally agree and actually in my actual code followed the exact practice also. I have shared a simplest example of my problem stmt here as didn't want to share unnecessary business logic. For the solution part it would cost me performance to keep saving all those information and that too just for logging.. so I dont think that would be best in this usecase maybe. :(

Comment: I do not understand your comment: You agree with my refactoring advice concerning IOSP (which would give you the desired information in the logs) and you also agree that manual book-keeping for logging is not a good idea. So why the sad smiley and why didn't you accept and upvote my correct answer? Is there anything else you need to know? Anything you do not understand?

Comment: Appreciate your effort to write an intuitive answer from your part. I am still looking for the solution of the original problem as quoted. Refactoring though is a good suggestion if one wants to print logs as you suggested but doesn't help solve the original problem i.e solving this problem using aspect. I have up voted though.

Comment: Well, I already explained what you need to do in order to record and subtract execution times per thread. So just do it if you think it makes sense. Like I said, it would be an effort to do it and never be perfect due to the bookkeeping overhead as such. What you are expecting now is that somebody does the whole job for you. It is no longer about answering a question by means of fixing broken code or refactoring as is usual on SO. Maybe you can incentivise someone to do your job by putting a 200 or so points bounty on the question if it is so important to you and you don't know how to start.

Comment: I just clicked on this question again accidentally and thought about the call tree thing again. I have a simpler solution on my mind now, but still it involves manual book-keeping concerning execution times per call stack depth and making sure some values are getting reset at specific execution points. But it is doable, says my thought experiment.