# How can I pass metadata from a Spring Boot application to a library?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

How should I go about passing data from a Spring Boot application to a library that the application uses (a library owned and controlled by me)?

Can this be done through a class-level annotation like `@GetMe(name = "foobar")` ? If yes, how can the `name` property then be retrieved by the library and used in its Java classes? Is the Java Reflection API a must-use in this case or is there a cleaner way to fetch an annotation's values?

Comment: Maybe AOP could help on this case with the combination of the annotation. 
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop. 

I believe you could easily intercept the method.

Comment: If I were to use the example `@Around` advice, could I inject the annotation somehow into the advice method? If yes, can I pass the values from that annotation to the method that Spring AOP is executing around (the method annotated with my custom annotation) ?

Comment: I believe you could. Here is a better example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21275958/4423575